# Blackman-Harris in C

Tags: c, math

I'm trying to replicate the function seen here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function#Blackman.E2.80.93Harris_window

But I simply can't get any sense making values. This is my current code:

```
double blackman_harris(int n, int N){
double a0, a1, a2, a3, seg1, seg2, seg3, w_n;
a0 = 0.35875;
a1 = 0.48829;
a2 = 0.14128;
a3 = 0.01168;

seg1 = a1 * (double) cos((double)(2*M_PI*n)/(double) (N - 1));
seg2 = a2 * (double) cos((double)(4*M_PI*n)/(double) (N - 1));
seg3 = a3 * (double) cos((double)(6*M_PI*n)/(double) (N - 1));

w_n = a0 - seg1 + seg2 - seg3;

return w_n;
}
```

Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: You should provide sample input and their respective expected output values.

Comment: What is not working ? The implementation seems fine. What are you expecting ?

Comment: Does M_PI have enough significant digits for your purpose? Big n and little N might throw you off a bit with too few M_PI significant digits.

Comment: I worry that M_PI is not a double and that the internal integer multiplies may be throwing you off.  Have you attempted to graph the results and see if they are what you expect?  If not, what is wrong with them?

Comment: I suggest you pass in x = double(n)/double(N-1) rather than two parameters n and N. This will reduce the complexity of your function and make it easy to graph. Have you compared your graph with that on the wikipedia link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define the window as a whole function.

```
bool VecBuildBlackmanHarrisWindow( float* pOut, unsigned int num )
{
    const float a0      = 0.35875f;
    const float a1      = 0.48829f;
    const float a2      = 0.14128f;
    const float a3      = 0.01168f;

    unsigned int idx    = 0;
    while( idx < num )
    {
        pOut[idx]   = a0 - (a1 * cosf( (2.0f * M_PI * idx) / (num - 1) )) + (a2 * cosf( (4.0f * M_PI * idx) / (num - 1) )) - (a3 * cosf( (6.0f * M_PI * idx) / (num - 1) ));
        idx++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You can then define a window function as follows:

```
std::vector< float > window( 1024 );
VecBuildBlackmanHarrisWindow( &window.front(), window.size() );
```

Which means you can pre-calculate the window function in advance.

At this point I'm sorry I have led you wrongly.  Sorry.  I checked my code and you calculate the value by averaging all the window sample values together and then dividing by 2 (effectively add them all up and divide by N/2).

```
float fTotal    = 1.0f;
auto iter   = window.begin();
while( iter != window.end() )
{
    fTotal  += *iter;
    iter++;
}

fTotal  /= 1024.0f;
fTotal  /= 2.0f;
```

This gives me a value of 0.17969f

(If you use a larger window this value will change hence the value I gave you before being slightly lower).

Apologies for the confusion

Comment: Your example of defining the window as a whole function makes sense, and the implementation is OK assuming you want a 'symmetric' window (which is what the factor of N-1 gives you). However, your power-of-two window length indicates to me that you're probably using this window for spectral analysis, and if so, you probably wand a 'periodic' window where the factor would be just N.

Comment: The stuff at the end about averaging the window sample values and dividing by two does not make sense. First, you start your sum with a value of 1, rather than 0. Second, the divide-by-two looks wrong. For spectral analysis, you do want to scale the window up by a factor similar to this, but the scale factor should be so that the mean value of the window is 1.0.